# Creating a live video stream with Node.js, Socket.io and P5.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, socket.io, p5.js

I'm trying to create a simple video stream on the local network. However, the current code throws the following error:

> ***Uncaught TypeError:*** Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

It seems that the `createCapture` object I'm receiving is different than the one I'm sending, hence why it can't be displayed. Could someone point out how to solve this?

Thanks,
Charles

#### Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
// Create the app
var app = express();

// Set up the server
// process.env.PORT is related to deploying on heroku
//var server = app.listen(3000);

var server = app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:  ' + 3000);
  });

app.use(express.static('public'));

// WebSocket Portion
// WebSockets work with the HTTP server
var socket = require('socket.io');

// Register a callback function to run when we have an individual connection
// This is run for each individual user that connects
var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket){
    console.log("New connection: " + socket.id);

    socket.on('camera', newFrame);

    function newFrame(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('camera', data);
        // for(var propertyName in data) {
        //  console.log(propertyName);
        // }
        //console.log(data.elt);
    }
}
```

#### Sketch.js

```
var socket;
var capture;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(innerWidth, innerHeight);
  background(0);

  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  capture.hide();

  socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
  
  socket.on('camera', newFrame);
  noStroke();
}

function newFrame(data){
    image(data, 0, 0, 640, 320);
}


function draw() {
  socket.emit('camera', capture);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `capture` as a parameter of your `draw()` function. This way you can make sure you are using the same `capture` variable!

```
function draw(capture) {
    socket.emit('camera', capture); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried with no luck. `capture` is a global variable so I don't see how it could be different.